# Como retornar todo conteúdo de um JSON?

Tags: php

Eu tenho um arquivo JSON nos seguinte modelo:

```
[
  {
     "id": 1
      "nome": "José"
  },
  {
     "id": 2
      "nome": "João"
  }

]
```

E estou fazendo o seguinte servidor JSON no PHP para que me retorne o JSON inteiro. Do modo que meu código esta ele apenas retorna cada posição 1 por vez

```
$path =  explode('/', $_GET['path']);
$contents = file_get_contents('tickets.json');

$json = json_decode($contents, true);

$method =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

header('Content-type: application/json');
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');

if ($method === 'GET') {
    if ($json[$path[0]]) {
        echo json_encode($json[$path[0]]);
     }else{
         echo '[]';
     }
}
```

Quando eu seto o `?path=0` ele me retorna a posição 0 com id 1 eu queria que ele retornasse tudo que esta dentro do json se eu não colocar nada no path e se eu colocar o ID no path ele me retorne apenas 1

Comment: Você quer que retorne todos os valores que estão no arquivo JSON quando recebe o valor 0 no GET?

Comment: @IsmaelSIlva Eu quero que se eu nao colocar nada ele me retorne todos e se eu colocar algo no path exemplo o ID e ele me retorne só um

Comment: Sua variável path, irá existir mesmo sem valor? Exemplo, "?path="

Comment: @IsmaelSIlva Não necessariamente, eu só quero um getAll se nao tiver um path ou se tiver o path um getById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde! 
Veja se dessa forma ajuda você

```
<?php

$path = null;
/**
    Condicional para verificar se a variável $_GET['path'] existe,
    caso exista é inserido o valor nele
**/
if(isset($_GET['path'])) {
    $path = $_GET['path'];
}
$contents = file_get_contents('tickets.json');

$json = json_decode($contents, true);

$method =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

header('Content-type: application/json');
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');

if ($method === 'GET') {
    /**
        verifica se é nula ou vazia ou se não inteiro (caso haja necessidade)
    **/
    if(is_null($path) || $path === '') {
        /**
            Retorna todos os dados do JSON
        **/
        echo json_encode($json);
    } else {
        if ($data = GetById($json, $path)) {
            echo json_encode($data);
        }else{
            echo '[]';
        }
    }
}

/**
    Fiz uma função para ficar mais organizado
**/
function GetById ($allData, $id) {
    $count = count($allData);
    /**
        Aqui é rodado um laço que verifica se o numero que venho na variável path é igual ao id do arquivo
    **/
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if($allData[$i]['id'] == $id) {
            /**
                Aqui ele dá o retorno para não precisar percorrer todos os dados,
                isso vai ajudar no desempenho da aplicação, pois só irá percorrer todos os dados se for necessário 
            **/
            return $allData[$i];
        }
    }
    /**
        retorna nulo se não encontrar nada
    **/
    return null;
}
```

Comment: esse metodo funcionou em partes mas eu nao consegui fazer o getbyid e o !is_int($path) eu tive que retirar para cair no else

Comment: Ok, vou modificar o código

Answer (score -1):

Você pode contar o numero de casas que contém o array e depois mandar imprimir em um loop.

Veja se esse exemplo te ajuda:

```
if ($method === 'GET') {
  if (count($json[$path]) == 1) {
    echo json_encode($json[$path[0]]);
  }
  else if(count($json[$path]) > 1) {
    $n = count($json[$path]);
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
    {
      echo json_encode($json[$path[$i]]);
    }
else{
         echo '[]';
     }
}
```